# I'm getting some logical error in Huffman's encoding java

Tags: java, huffman-code

Here is the code...

```
public class Huffman_Coding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string to compress: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        HashString hs = new HashString();

        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = hs.getStringHash(str);

        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        for (char ch : hm.keySet()) {
            pq.add(new Node(null, null, hm.get(ch), ch));
        }
        System.out.println(pq);
        while (pq.size() != 1) {
            Node left = pq.poll();
            Node right = pq.poll();
            Node parent = new Node(left, right, left.freq + right.freq, '\0');
            pq.add(parent);
            System.out.println(pq);
        }
        Huffman_Tree ht = new Huffman_Tree();
        String ans = "";
        ht.inOrder(pq.poll(), ans);
    }
}

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [freq=" + freq + ", ch=" + ch + "]";
    }

    Node lptr;
    Node rptr;
    int freq;
    char ch;

    Node(Node lptr, Node rptr, int freq, char ch) {
        this.freq = freq;
        this.lptr = lptr;
        this.rptr = rptr;
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node o) {

        int comparedvalue = Integer.compare(this.freq, o.freq);
        if (comparedvalue != 0)
            return comparedvalue;
        else
            return Integer.compare(this.ch, o.ch);
        }
    }

    boolean isLeaf() {
        return this.lptr == null && this.rptr == null;
    }
}

class Huffman_Tree {
    void inOrder(Node root, String code) {
        if (!root.isLeaf()) {
            inOrder(root.lptr, code + '0');
            inOrder(root.rptr, code + '1');

        } else
            System.out.println(root.ch + " : " + code);

    }
}
```

Here, for input string `abccddeeee`,
I'm getting something like:

```
[Node [freq=1, ch=a], Node [freq=1, ch=b], Node [freq=2, ch=c], Node [freq=2, ch=d], Node [freq=4, ch=e]]
[Node [freq=2, ch= ]]
```

I'm confused why in the second step Node having 'd' is coming ahead from 'e'. This is getting me errors in final encoding. Why compareTo method is failing I cant understand.

getHashString returns a Hash which has characters in key and their freq in value.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `HashString` class, in order to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why the order of the elements in `PriorityQueue` is not the expected one after *polling* elements ant *adding* new "synthetic" elements, but I think you can solve the problem switching to a `TreeSet`, as I have done with success with

```
TreeSet<Node> pq = new TreeSet<Node>((n1, n2) -> n1.compareTo(n2)); // explicit but unnecessary comparator
```

and changind each `pq.poll()` invocation into `pq.pollFirst()`...

I hope this workaround can help you!

EDIT

As you can read in [official `PriorityQueue` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), * The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).*

**This should explain why the `toString()` method invocation shows queue elements in an order different than the expected priority order...**